# Will programs use the paging file if it's on another partition?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

For example, let's say that paging file is enabled on D: drive and not enabled on C: drive. Will programs installed and running on C: use that paging file or does it require a paging file for each partition?

Comment: google Page File to learn what it is please, then ask questions.

Answer (score 5):

The **system** manages memory paging.
It is not in the domain of any individual application, it is entirely in the hands of the OS itself.